# Do interaction terms improve the standard ARIMA model $X_t=\alpha_1X_{t-1}+\alpha_2X_{t-2}+\alpha_3X_{t-1}X_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$? If so, how to code?

Tags: arima, interaction

Does an ARIMA model appended with interaction terms $X_t=\alpha_1X_{t-1}+\alpha_2X_{t-2}+\alpha_3X_{t-1}X_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$ makes sense? And if so, how to code that?

I know ARIMA is limited by the power of rational-numbers, but would adding interaction terms make it more generalizable or powerful?

Comment: This is not done in "standard" ARIMA. You could of course set up a model like this and estimate it via OLS (not optimal for ARIMA) and see where it takes you. I would assume this would get unstable very quickly, so I don't think it would be very useful.

Comment: As @StephanKolassa said no, it is not "standard" but instead of coding it as an ARIMAX model, coding it up as a "standard" regression model assuming $X_{t-i}$ as explanatory features and sticking an ARMA error structure to it should be trivial to code and would account both for the interaction as well as any residual serial correlation.

Comment: Maybe related to so-called *bilinear* timeseries models?

Comment: There is no MA part that I can see, so I would refer to AR rather than ARIMA.